# How to decode python string

Tags: python, encryption

I have some code which I would like to be decoded but not having much luck in guessing what the codepage is, if any is being used. Any help would be much appreciated.
i am using python command line in windows 7 pc,if any python guru guide me how to decrypt and see the code thaat would be appreciated.

```
exec("import re;import base64");exec((lambda p,y:(lambda o,b,f:re.sub(o,b,f))(r"([0-9a-f]+)",lambda m:p(m,y),base64.b64decode("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")))(lambda a,b:b[int("0x"+a.group(1),16)],"0|1|addonfolder|xbmc|translatePath|path|script_name|xbmcgui|script_chk|downloader|scriptname|xbmcaddon|getCondVisibility|UpdateLocalAddons|download|supermax|Addon|lib|supermaxwizard|special|DialogProgress|INSTALL|website|SuperMaxWizard|extract|dialog|remove|except|join|plugin|os|addons|Installing|dp|UnloadSkin|print|COLOR|video|ReloadSkin|FORCECLOSE|Installer|Installed|def|Main|pass|home|HasAddon|SuperMax|packages|Brought|Success|return|update|url|Please|Dialog|create|try|Wizard|Nearly|System|com|zip|addon|Wait|been|else|http|quit|XBMC|gold|Done|all|has|You|not|sm|MP|By|if|ok|To|s|executebuiltin|import".split("|")))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, also add some row breaks instead of having one huge one liner with semi colons separating them. There's different strings here in play. One sure does look like base64.

Comment: @Torxed: There is no indentation to fix, it's uglified and only has one line.

Comment: @Amadam i thought I'd be a good sport and give OP a chance to neaten it up before telling them it's uglified. :)

Comment: @Torxed: It is not ugly code that you can just neaten up; it has been intentionally run through an uglifier, and it might not be immediately obvious to the beginners where to even start trying to pull it apart.

Answer (score 4):

The code is uglified. You can unobfuscate it yourself by executing the contents of `exec(...)` in your Python shell.

```
import re
import base64
print ((lambda p,y.....split("|")))
```

EDIT: As snakecharmerb says, it is generally not safe to execute unknown code. I analysed the code to find that running the insides of `exec` will only decrypt, and leaving off the `exec` itself will just result in a string. This procedure ("execute stuff inside exec") is by no means a generally safe method to decrypt uglified code, and you need to actually analyse what it does. But, at this point, I was asking you to trust my judgement, which, if it is wrong, theoretically could expose you to an attack. In addition, it seems you have problems getting it to run on your Python; so here's what I'm getting from the above:

```
import xbmcaddon
import xbmcgui
import xbmc
import os
import downloader
import extract
addon       = xbmcaddon.Addon()
website   = "http://supermaxwizard.com/sm/plugin.video.supermax-MP.zip"
scriptname = "plugin.video.supermax"
def script_chk(script_name):
        return xbmc.getCondVisibility('System.HasAddon(%s)' % script_name) == 1

def INSTALL(url):
        path = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons','packages'))
        print path
        dp = xbmcgui.DialogProgress()
        dp.create("Addon Installer","Installing Addon..",'', 'Please Wait')
        lib=os.path.join(path, 'download.zip')
        try:
                os.remove(lib)
        except:
                pass
                downloader.download(url, lib, dp)
                addonfolder = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home','addons'))
                print addonfolder
                dp.update(0,"", "Nearly Done")
                extract.all(lib,addonfolder,dp)

                xbmc.executebuiltin('UnloadSkin()'); 
                xbmc.executebuiltin('ReloadSkin()');
                xbmc.executebuiltin("XBMC.UpdateLocalAddons()"); 
                dialog=xbmcgui.Dialog(); dialog.ok("Success!","SuperMax Wizard has been Installed","   [COLOR gold]Brought To You By SuperMaxWizard.com[/COLOR]")
                """
                try:
                        os.remove(lib)
                except:
                        pass
                        #FORCECLOSE()
                else:quit()
                """

def Main():
        if not script_chk(scriptname):
                INSTALL(website)



Main()
```

Comment: is it worth pointing out that calling exec on unknown/untrusted code is risky?

Comment: thanks for response.I did try that but get error message.

Comment: Tks.so which version of python u used to decrypt it.i will try that.tks

Comment: I didn't write it, I just decrypted it.

Comment: i get SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

>>> import zlib
>>> import base64
>>> import re

  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>>

Comment: can u pls help me decrypting this too,.https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74353742/default.py    
i get SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal >>> import zlib >>> import base64 >>> import re ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal >>>